# image with link and keep it centered

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

Hi I am trying to add an image with a link and keep it centered and my code isn't working can you help?

<img src="flower.jpg" width="82" height="86" class="centerImage" " title="White flower" alt="Flower">

Answer (score 1):

Just add some style to change `<img />` from inline element to block element and use margin to center it.

For example

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img width="80" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659574087501-92ef4aa7b2d8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1374&q=80" alt="demo"/>
</a>
```

Hope this might help you